# 'asm' operand has impossible constraints

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, archlinux, xen

I'm trying to compile xen on Arch linux and getting following error:

```
src/stacks.c:342:5: error: 'asm' operand has impossible constraints
 asm volatile(
 ^
```

Here is code for the method that is causing error:

```
void
run_thread(void (*func)(void*), void *data)
{
ASSERT32FLAT();
if (! CONFIG_THREADS || ! ThreadControl)
    goto fail;
struct thread_info *thread;
thread = memalign_tmphigh(THREADSTACKSIZE, THREADSTACKSIZE);
if (!thread)
    goto fail;

dprintf(DEBUG_thread, "/%08x\\ Start thread\n", (u32)thread);
thread->stackpos = (void*)thread + THREADSTACKSIZE;
struct thread_info *cur = getCurThread();
hlist_add_after(&thread->node, &cur->node);
asm volatile(
    // Start thread
    "  pushl $1f\n"                 // store return pc
    "  pushl %%ebp\n"               // backup %ebp
    "  movl %%esp, (%%edx)\n"       // cur->stackpos = %esp
    "  movl (%%ebx), %%esp\n"       // %esp = thread->stackpos
    "  calll *%%ecx\n"              // Call func

    // End thread
    "  movl %%ebx, %%eax\n"         // %eax = thread
    "  movl 4(%%ebx), %%ebx\n"      // %ebx = thread->node.next
    "  movl (%5), %%esp\n"          // %esp = MainThread.stackpos
    "  calll %4\n"                  // call __end_thread(thread)
    "  movl -4(%%ebx), %%esp\n"     // %esp = next->stackpos
    "  popl %%ebp\n"                // restore %ebp
    "  retl\n"                      // restore pc
    "1:\n"
    : "+a"(data), "+c"(func), "+b"(thread), "+d"(cur)
    : "m"(*(u8*)__end_thread), "m"(MainThread)
    : "esi", "edi", "cc", "memory");
return;

fail:
    func(data);
}
```

I'm not sure what's going on. Can someone with assebly knowledge help look at it and tell if there is some obvious problem here?

**Update:**

You can fix this error by doing 2 things:

1. add COMMONCFLAGS += $(call cc-option,$(CC),-fstack-check=no,) into seabios makefile (if you build xen from git AUR then location should be xen/src/xen-4.5.1/tools/firmware/seabios-dir-remote/Makefile)
2. go to stacks.c and change movl (%5), %%esp to movl %5, %%esp

Comment: I've just installed xen from AUR and it worked. I'm using 64bits arch. What's your arch, gcc versions?

Comment: Where is it from exactly? I couldn't find it in official xen sources... The immediate problem is that the compiler runs out of registers if not using `-fomit-frame-pointer` (which is automatically enabled when optimizing, maybe you are not). However, with that enabled, the compiler will use `ebp` and that may conflict with the asm and end up with bad output. It's unclear whether `ebp` is changed or not (why push it if it isn't).

Comment: Any chance you are building this on 32-bit Linux (or targeting a 32-bit build) and this code is being generated as PIC(position independent code)? If so you can't use `ebx` as an output (or clobber) constraint.

Comment: @Jester Looks like the SeaBIOS code. I believe that Xen can be configured to use it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks it seems it is SeaBIOS indeed.

Comment: I'm building latest xen from AUR. The only customization that I've made was recompiling binutils with --enable-targets=x86_64-pep to enable UEFI support. If you look at comments here https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/xen/ you would notice that people are having similar problems.

Comment: After `COMMONCFLAGS += $(call cc-option,$(CC),-fno-stack-protector-all,)` try adding `COMMONCFLAGS += $(call cc-option,$(CC),-fstack-check=no,)` . Also make sure the `-fPIC` entry you added is deleted. See what happens

Comment: @MichaelPetch Interesting. Error message has changed:
src/stacks.c:349: Error: missing ')'
src/stacks.c:349: Error: junk `(%ebp))' after expression
Full trace here http://paste.ofcode.org/3a2f3xsqEeypMh5ay6Fa28q
stacks.c source here: http://paste.ofcode.org/SXWbTnWegRyjmpYpzmSxMx

Comment: Try changing `movl (%5), %%esp\n` to `movl %5, %%esp\n` . The good news is that it has got past the constraint problem

Comment: Unless of course you are using Jester's changes - and that would likely be `movl (%4), %%esp\n`  changed to `movl %4, %%esp\n`

Comment: It seems that worked! Now it's giving me a different error though but it's  for a different file (also in this stupid seabios module).
http://paste.ofcode.org/6D7mjhpnEE3BmQcvVtSPW9

Comment: Have you considered pulling out the git version of the seabios module? There are a number of these things fixed for a number of months. `git clone git://git.seabios.org/seabios.git seabios` . I think the XEN AUR version is a bit behind the times. My suggestion for `-fstack-check=no` being added came from a bug report that seabios fixed. Quite a few problems seemed to involve 32 bit builds on system like Arch that use extra CFLAGS for hardening software. As well,  some fixes are related to problems found when compiling with newer clang and gcc compilers.

Comment: You won't believe there is some other sh** with the version from repo.
Also in asm code... also in stacks.c...
src/stacks.c:567: Error: missing ')'
src/stacks.c:567: Error: junk `(%ebp))' after expression

Comment: That is the same type of problem as `movl (%5), %%esp` . Those extra parentheses shouldn't be there since the constraint `m` is being used. I am guessing some compilers/assemblers(also depending on default options used on a platform) are more stringent about what syntax is allowed. Near line 567 you will find this `"  movl (%5), %%esp\n"` change it to `"  movl %5, %%esp\n"`

Comment: Yeah you are right but it leads to the same type of problem that I had with an oder version of seabios: Makefile:175: recipe for target 'out/rom16.o' failed
make[6]: *** [out/rom16.o] Error 1
I think it's better to move it to the separate discussion to keep this one focused on the issue related to asm which can be considered resolved at this point.

Comment: I've created a new thread for that issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33952875/xenarch-recipe-for-target-out-rom16-o-failed
Thank you for helping out with this!

Answer (score 3):

The immediate cause is probably that you don't have `-fomit-frame-pointer` enabled, either directly or indirectly through optimization switches. Thus, the compiler runs out of registers since `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx` and `edx` are used for arguments, `esi` and `edi` are clobbers and `ebp` is the frame pointer. The solution is therefore to make sure this option is enabled.

Apparently [this code is part of SeaBIOS](http://git.qemu.org/?p=seabios.git;a=blob;f=src/stacks.c;h=ef6a707751615fe059a44b455b46051a2e931456;hb=master#l545) (thanks to Michael Petch for finding it). `__end_thread` there is simply a function, as opposed to a function pointer one would expect from the presence of that casting magic. As such, I think the point of this construct is to work around any eventual name mangling. Unfortunately, it sacrifices a register for that purpose. If you know you your environment does not mangle function names, you can use this simpler version which doesn't need an extra register and should compile fine in debug builds with a frame pointer too:

```
asm volatile(
    // Start thread
    "  pushl $1f\n"                 // store return pc
    "  pushl %%ebp\n"               // backup %ebp
    "  movl %%esp, (%%edx)\n"       // cur->stackpos = %esp
    "  movl (%%ebx), %%esp\n"       // %esp = thread->stackpos
    "  calll *%%ecx\n"              // Call func

    // End thread
    "  movl %%ebx, %%eax\n"         // %eax = thread
    "  movl 4(%%ebx), %%ebx\n"      // %ebx = thread->node.next
    "  movl (%4), %%esp\n"          // %esp = MainThread.stackpos
    "  call __end_thread\n"         // call __end_thread(thread)
    "  movl -4(%%ebx), %%esp\n"     // %esp = next->stackpos
    "  popl %%ebp\n"                // restore %ebp
    "  retl\n"                      // restore pc
    "1:\n"
    : "+a"(data), "+c"(func), "+b"(thread), "+d"(cur)
    : "m"(MainThread)
    : "esi", "edi", "cc", "memory");
```

Comment: I like your answer, but I'm still scratching my head. The "r" constraint isn't being used so I don't see how the compiler would be forced into choosing an available scratch register (I may be missing something in what you are saying)

Comment: It wouldn't need to, but it's not smart enough to figure out that the `*(u8*)__end_thread` is just `__end_thread` as a memory reference. So it loads that address into `%ebp` and uses `(%ebp)` instead. With optimization enabled that's not a problem, it does then figure that out. With `-fomit-frame-pointer` it's not a problem either, because it can use `ebp`. Seems to be a `gcc` issue only, `clang` and `icc` handle this even without optimization.

Comment: Fair enough Jester (I was one of your upvoters). I happened to miss that point before my morning coffee

Comment: You should instead add `-O2` or `-O3` to the build options or make sure you are not doing a debug build. Unless you **are** trying to make a debug build of course.

Comment: Where those options should go? Xen PKGBUILD file?
I see there is a call to make:
    "make LANG=C PYTHON=python2"
but I'm not sure if that's a right place to add the flag.

Comment: You could try adding `CFLAGS=-O2` there at the end of the line.

Comment: So... Xen itself compiles with -O2 already and it's doing well our problem is in SeaBIOS package and it has a separate Makefile. I've tried -O2, -O2 there (-fomit-frame-pointer is already there) but it didn't have any effect.
Also I've tried to modify actual function applying your suggested fix - still same results...

Comment: @fury : Assuming all that is true, does `-fPIC` appear as an option?

Comment: @MichaelPetch : I've added it to COMMONCFLAGS in the SeaBIOS Makefile. Just in case I've posted it here http://paste.ofcode.org/3449NSzMqcgN2mMrjgFUMGH
Got the same error during compile. :(
I've started thinking if I actually need this code since I was going to use EFI eventually.

Comment: @fury Oh no, I asked because `-fPIC` would likely be a source of a potential problem. If it wasn't there to begin with don't add it.

Comment: @fury Are you using `gcc` or `gcc-multilib`?

Comment: @MichaelPetch Anyway that flag doesn't matter here :)
I have multilib enabled in pacman.conf so I guess gcc is multilib.
# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 5.2.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: `-fPIC` would matter here if it was on. Because then you can't have the `+b` constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I'd completely rewrite the asm statement. The basic problem is that the statement either clobbers or uses as an input/output operand every register except EBP. When optimization is disabled and `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` is used there isn't a register to store the result of evaluating the expression `(u8*)__end_thread`. Which is a good thing because it because if the frame pointer was available it would generate `calll (%ebp)` which isn't what is actually wanted here.

Instead of trying assign all the registers and clobbering any that aren't used, the following asm statement makes every register except EBP an output operand. This gives the compiler much more freedom to assign input registers.

```
int dummy;
asm volatile("push 1f\n\t"
         "push %%ebp\n\t"
         "mov %%esp, %[cur_stackpos]\n\t"
         "mov %[thread_stackpos], %%esp\n\t"
         "call *%[func]\n\t"
         "mov %p[mainthread_stackpos], %%esp\n\t"
         "mov %[thread], %%eax\n\t"
         "call %c[end_thread]\n\t"
         "mov 4(%[thread]),%%eax\n\t"
         "mov -4(%%eax),%%esp\n\t"
         "pop %%ebp\n\t"
         "pop %%eax\n\t"
         "jmp *%%eax\n\t"
         "1:\n"
         : 
         [data] "+a" (data),
         "=b" (dummy), "=c" (dummy), "=d" (dummy),
         "=S" (dummy), "=D" (dummy)
         :
         [func] "r" (func),
         [cur_stackpos] "m" (cur->stackpos),
         [thread_stackpos] "rm" (thread->stackpos),
         [mainthread_stackpos] "i" (&MainThread.stackpos),
         [thread] "bSD" (thread),
         [end_thread] "i" (__end_thread)
         : 
         "memory", "cc");
```

I've used `"i"` constraints and operand modifiers for the `[mainthread_stackpos]` and `[end_thread]` operands to ensure that these operands are simple labels. The compiler can't put them in registers or on the stack. This is a bit of paranoia, using an `"m"` constraint without operand modifiers will also work. At least until the compiler does something unexpected like it did with  `*(u8*)__end_thread`. Speaking of which, I've replaced it with just `__end_thread` as the cast and dereference seems to be pointless.

I've also replaced the `ret` statement with `pop %eax; jmp *%eax` as this should be faster. The `ret` statement will always be mispredicted because the address won't be return stack buffer, but there's at least chance that `jmp *eax` will be predicted. It either jumps to the next instruction or the `1:` label in `switch_stacks`.

Comment: Unfortunatelly after using fix that you've suggested above I'm still getting same error: "src/stacks.c:343:2: error: impossible constraint in 'asm'"
Also please note that there is working solution described in comments and in post update that solves this problem (but leads to another) Thank you for you time though!

Comment: @fury I did test it fairly extensively, but obviously I can't reproduce the specific circumstances you're compiling the code under.